# Cron job for multiple user

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, phpmyadmin

Currently i have cron job which is work fine but its only for single user -

Currently we using cron job like this single user id - command

```
/usr/bin/GET http://Mydomain/getdetails?userid=18
```

In getdetails

```
public function getdetails() {

     $userid =trim($_GET['userid']);
```

is there any way can do this for multiple user Or current session user?

Comment: In a _cron_ job - who is the current session user?

Comment: I dont think you have asked your question

Comment: At the moment it manually we using like 18. it possible to get id from database run the corn job?

Comment: Your whole concept of a cron job is wrong. You *dont* use URLs for  that except you call some kind of service. Use a shell instead.